# what smartphone features can be restricted for iOS, Android, Windows phones?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, mobile, windows-mobile

We are working on a mobile app with a feature that allows parents to restrict or disable certain phone functions on their children's devices.

I have been googling for this for a while and can't find an adequate search term.

Ultimately I would like to create a table that outlines various phone features and indicates whether a native mobile application can restrict or disable it. This will be used to indicate the differences between iOS, Android, and Windows Phone development capabilities.

Some features I am looking to modify are: app use, phone calls, text messages, internet access, etc. For restrictions such as phone calls and texts, I'd also like to determine if we can allow a "white list" of allowed contacts.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone doesn't have any mechanisms to allow one app to restrict what the user / other apps can do. It does have the [Kids Corner feature](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/people/set-up-kids-corner) that enables parents to limit what apps a child can use (and some features within those apps, like In-App-Purchases) but not individual features.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Is there any online resources that show what restrictions are in place for windows development?

Answer (score 1):

iOS already has a pretty rich parental control center built into the Settings app. I don't believe there is an API that would allow you access those features either. In general, this type of inter-app communication is very limited on iOS.

Comment: Thank you for the response. What I want in particular is some sort of list from Apple that outlines what apps CAN'T do, such as communicating with other apps, working with the core functions of the device, etc. I understand that there are lots of restrictions, but I can't seem to find a list of what's not allowed, nothing from Apple either. I only see third-party sources claiming these things. Not that I don't believe them, but one of my clients wants proof.